# Create container cadvisor An error occurred mountpoint for cpu not found

Tags: linux

Description

Steps to reproduce the issue:

1.Create container cadvisor

`docker run   --volume=/:/rootfs:ro   --volume=/var/run:/var/run:ro   --volume=/sys:/sys:ro   --volume=/var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro   --volume=/dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro   --publish=8080:8080   --detach=true   --name=cadvisor   --privileged   --device=/dev/kmsg  google/cadvisor`

2.Container status exitd(255)

Describe the results you received:

use `docker logs cadvisor`

Get error

`F0518 02:42:13.384527 1 cadvisor.go:146] Failed to create a Container Manager: mountpoint for cpu not found`

Describe the results you expected:

Create a cadvisor container based on official documentation

Additional information you deem important (e.g. issue happens only occasionally):

Output of docker version:

```
 Version:           20.10.15
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.17.9
 Git commit:        fd82621
 Built:             Thu May  5 13:21:10 2022
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.15
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.17.9
  Git commit:       4433bf6
  Built:            Thu May  5 13:19:15 2022
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.4
  GitCommit:        212e8b6fa2f44b9c21b2798135fc6fb7c53efc16
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.1
  GitCommit:        v1.1.1-0-g52de29d
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0
```

Output of docker info:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc., v0.8.2-docker)
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc., v2.5.0)
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc., v0.17.0)

Server:
 Containers: 2
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 2
 Images: 1
 Server Version: 20.10.15
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: systemd
 Cgroup Version: 2
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux runc io.containerd.runc.v2
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 212e8b6fa2f44b9c21b2798135fc6fb7c53efc16
 runc version: v1.1.1-0-g52de29d
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: default
  cgroupns
 Kernel Version: 5.15.0-25-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 2
 Total Memory: 1.897GiB
 Name: mjz-ubuntu-docker-vm
 ID: EUGI:MOZM:NUH7:777V:4RHU:G64V:OTAH:UVQR:AS7H:NNMV:3KIN:TQHM
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Registry Mirrors:
  https://a8x1qfbv.mirror.aliyuncs.com/
 Live Restore Enabled: false

WARNING: API is accessible on http://192.168.117.59:2375 without encryption.
         Access to the remote API is equivalent to root access on the host. Refer
         to the 'Docker daemon attack surface' section in the documentation for
         more information: https://docs.docker.com/go/attack-surface/
```

Additional environment details (AWS, VirtualBox, physical, etc.):

Using VM virtual machine version 15.1

Ubuntu version

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should no longer use cAdvisor image from Docker Hub as they are no longer updated (see deprecation notice in [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cadvisor)), but instead use `gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor` and the desired version. You can check the release versions [here](https://github.com/google/cadvisor/releases).

I have stumbled upon this issue myself and in my case, it turned out to be that a more recent version of Amazon Linux which somehow made cAdvisor throwing that error.
Specifically, I am using ECS and I am selecting the image through SSM parameters. My team recently switched to `/aws/service/ecs/optimized-ami/amazon-linux-2022/recommended/image_id` AMI and it took a while to realize this particular image caused the issue.
As soon as we went back to use `/aws/service/ecs/optimized-ami/amazon-linux-2/recommended/image_id` cAdvisor worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Simple change the image name
replace the image with gcr.io/cadvisor/cadvisor
Boom fixed!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, yes I've fixed this issue